# Adapter call fails after enabling Application Authenticity

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I've tried to enable Basic Application Authenticity for the sample "[OfflineAuthentication](https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/7.1/advanced-topics/offline-authentication/)" hybrid iOS app. However, the adapter call fails, any ideas?

***Here's the code:***

authenticationConfig.xml:

```
<customSecurityTest name="myCustomSecurityTest">
  <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="1"/>
  <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="myCustomRealm"/>
  <test isInternalDeviceID="true" realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" step="2"/>
</customSecurityTest>
<!--DO i need to include wl_authenticityRealm here as well?-->
<customSecurityTest name="SubscribeServlet">
  <test isInternalUserID="true" realm="SubscribeServlet"/>
</customSecurityTest>
```

application-descriptor.xml:

```
<iphone bundleId="com.OfflineAuthSample" applicationId="OfflineAuthSample" version="1.0" securityTest="myCustomSecurityTest">
```

***MobileFirst Console shows basic app authenticity is enabled***
[image]

***Here's the log:***

```
2016-10-01 18:20:34.518875 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] DiskCookieStorage changing policy from 2 to 0, cookie file: file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/7F4A0DF9-95B0-4C21-AC73-9A758BAD1DE9/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies 2016-10-01 18:20:34.647379 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_SPLASH] -[WLSplashView updateImage] in WLSplashView.m:189 :: Splash screen image is taken from UILaunchImages: Default-736h 2016-10-01 18:20:34.681607 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_SPLASH] -[WLSplashView updateImage] in WLSplashView.m:189 :: Splash screen image is taken from UILaunchImages: Default-736h 2016-10-01 18:20:34.683230 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] Unbalanced calls to begin/end appearance transitions for <UIViewController: 0x10090d0c0>. 2016-10-01 18:20:34.701919 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252879] [DEBUG] [WL_CONFIG] -[WLConfig init] in WLConfig.m:71 :: {
    "application id" = OfflineAuthSample;
    "application version" = "1.0";
    authenticitySharedData = "${authenticitySharedData}";
    buildtime = 1475317232;
    environment = iphone;
    host = "52.77.249.78";
    ignoredFileExtensions = "";
    platformVersion = "7.1.0.0";
    port = 9080;
    protocol = http;
    testWebResourcesChecksum = false;
    wlAppFamily = "";
    wlMainFile = "index.html";
    wlSecureDirectUpdatePublicKey = "";
    wlServerContext = "/testssl/";
    wlShareCookies = "";
    wlShareUserCert = false;
    wlUid = "dB6EhEirkRwkU04A5lgiRw=="; } 2016-10-01 18:20:34.703147 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252879] [DEBUG] [WL_INIT] -[WLImpl initWL] in WLImpl.m:127 :: At first launch 2016-10-01 18:20:34.706276 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252879] [DEBUG] [WL_INIT] -[WLImpl initWL] in WLImpl.m:153 :: Web resources should not be extracted. 2016-10-01 18:20:34.902355 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] Apache Cordova native platform version 3.7.0 is starting. 2016-10-01 18:20:34.902559 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] Multi-tasking -> Device: YES, App: YES 2016-10-01 18:20:34.908168 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] Unlimited access to network resources 2016-10-01 18:20:34.910140 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] 

Started backup to iCloud! Please be careful. Your application might be rejected by Apple if you store too much data. For more information please read "iOS Data Storage Guidelines" at: https://developer.apple.com/icloud/documentation/data-storage/ To disable web storage backup to iCloud, set the BackupWebStorage preference to "local" in the Cordova config.xml file

2016-10-01 18:20:34.916050 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [CDVTimer][wlapp] 0.979006ms 2016-10-01 18:20:34.916196 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [CDVTimer][push] 0.092983ms 2016-10-01 18:20:34.916226 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [CDVTimer][TotalPluginStartup] 1.177967ms 2016-10-01 18:20:35.073631 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] Resetting plugins due to page load. 2016-10-01 18:20:35.123413 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] Finished load of: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/A7F58C8C-D71F-4178-A912-3138602AF24A/OfflineAuthSample.app/www/skinLoader.html 2016-10-01 18:20:35.239499 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] Resetting plugins due to page load. 2016-10-01 18:20:35.332761 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] Finished load of: file:///var/containers/Bundle/Application/A7F58C8C-D71F-4178-A912-3138602AF24A/OfflineAuthSample.app/www/default/index.html 2016-10-01 18:20:35.366708 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] log1 2016-10-01 18:20:35.383488 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252854] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2015/09/14 00:19:02 2016-10-01 18:20:35.805118 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252880] [DEBUG] [NONE] wlclient init started 2016-10-01 18:20:35.806879 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252852] [DEBUG] [NONE] ondeviceready event dispatched 2016-10-01 18:20:35.808544 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252854] [DEBUG] [NONE] Read cookies: null 2016-10-01 18:20:35.810495 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252860] [DEBUG] [NONE] CookieMgr read cookies: {} 2016-10-01 18:20:35.812504 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252855] [DEBUG] [NONE] before: initOptions.onSuccess 2016-10-01 18:20:35.814665 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252853] [DEBUG] [NONE] after: initOptions.onSuccess 2016-10-01 18:20:35.816615 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252880] [DEBUG] [NONE] added onPause and onResume event handlers 2016-10-01 18:20:35.818603 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252934] [DEBUG] [NONE] wlclient init success 2016-10-01 18:20:37.650366 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] WLReachability Flag Status: WR t------ networkStatusForFlags 2016-10-01 18:20:37.664856 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] THREAD WARNING: ['NetworkDetector'] took '15.065186' ms. Plugin should use a background thread. 2016-10-01 18:20:37.666274 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252852] [ERROR] [NONE] Unknown realm [myCustomRealm]. null returned for key: isUserAuthenticated 2016-10-01 18:20:37.667460 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT]
+[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2015/09/14 00:19:02 2016-10-01 18:20:37.669136 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252880] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [/apps/services/api/OfflineAuthSample/iphone/login] 2016-10-01 18:20:37.675317 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager removeCertificate:] in WLCertManager.m:243 :: Certificate successfully removed. 2016-10-01 18:20:37.686451 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager removeKey:] in WLCertManager.m:262 :: Key was successfully removed. 2016-10-01 18:20:37.691977 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager removeKey:] in WLCertManager.m:262 :: Key was successfully removed. 2016-10-01 18:20:37.708057 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT]
+[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2015/09/14 00:19:02 2016-10-01 18:20:37.709332 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AUTH] -[WLAuthorizationManager invokeInstanceRegistrationRequestWithCompletionHandler:] in WLAuthorizationManager.m:548 :: Call instance registration endpoint 2016-10-01 18:20:37.750096 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager generateKeyPair:withPublicKeyLabel:withKeySize:] in WLCertManager.m:225 :: generateKeyPair generating keypair --> Success 2016-10-01 18:20:37.756561 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2015/09/14 00:19:02 2016-10-01 18:20:37.757615 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
+[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:52 :: Request url is http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/authorization/v1/clients/instance 2016-10-01 18:20:37.759117 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:142 :: Request timeout is 10.000000 2016-10-01 18:20:37.760509 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST]
-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:221 :: Sending request (http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/authorization/v1/clients/instance) with headers:  {
    "Accept-Language" = "en-US";
    "User-Agent" = "OfflineAuthSample/1.0 (iPhone; iOS 10.0.1; Scale/3.00)/WLNativeAPI/7.1.0.0";
    "X-Requested-With" = XMLHttpRequest;
    "x-wl-app-version" = "1.0";
    "x-wl-device-id" = "A886EC57-DA81-4CF0-8F2D-9A2378124BCB";
    "x-wl-platform-version" = "7.1.0.0"; } You can see the request body in the Analytics platform logs. 2016-10-01 18:20:37.765230 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:320 :: Starting the request with URL http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/authorization/v1/clients/instance 2016-10-01 18:20:37.766217 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] __42-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:]_block_invoke in WLRequest.m:231 :: waiting for response... (Thread=<NSThread: 0x174073a00>{number = 1, name = main}) 2016-10-01 18:20:37.767243 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] THREAD WARNING: ['WLAuthorizationManagerPlugin'] took '101.814941' ms. Plugin should use a background thread. 2016-10-01 18:20:38.649720 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:352 :: Request Failed 2016-10-01 18:20:38.651924 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:353 :: Response Status Code : 401 2016-10-01 18:20:38.653315 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFailed:error:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:354 :: Response Error : Request failed: unauthorized (401) 2016-10-01 18:20:38.656197 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2015/09/14 00:19:02 2016-10-01 18:20:38.663312 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
+[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:52 :: Request url is http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/authorization/v1/clients/instance 2016-10-01 18:20:38.665685 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:142 :: Request timeout is 10.000000 2016-10-01 18:20:38.667459 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST]
-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:221 :: Sending request (http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/authorization/v1/clients/instance) with headers:  {
    "Accept-Language" = "en-US";
    Authorization = "{\"wl_authenticityRealm\":\"1cmUeOcbV/wyYuPi6FRi7/cndEWc8Jg/umF6tuIiUTo=\"}";
    "User-Agent" = "OfflineAuthSample/1.0 (iPhone; iOS 10.0.1; Scale/3.00)/WLNativeAPI/7.1.0.0";
    "X-Requested-With" = XMLHttpRequest;
    "x-wl-app-version" = "1.0";
    "x-wl-device-id" = "A886EC57-DA81-4CF0-8F2D-9A2378124BCB";
    "x-wl-platform-version" = "7.1.0.0"; } You can see the request body in the Analytics platform logs. 2016-10-01 18:20:38.670973 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:320 :: Starting the request with URL http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/authorization/v1/clients/instance 2016-10-01 18:20:38.672750 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] __42-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:]_block_invoke in WLRequest.m:231 :: waiting for response... (Thread=<NSThread: 0x174073a00>{number = 1, name = main}) 2016-10-01 18:20:38.850841 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:333 :: Request Success 2016-10-01 18:20:38.852492 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:334 :: Response Status Code : 200 2016-10-01 18:20:38.856083 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:335 :: Response Content : {"certificate":"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"} 2016-10-01 18:20:38.858704 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2015/09/14 00:19:02 2016-10-01 18:20:38.862329 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFinished:] in WLRequest.m:365 :: Response Header: {
    "Content-Length" = 878;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json;charset=UTF-8";
    Date = "Sat, 01 Oct 2016 10:20:29 GMT";
    "X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/3.0"; } Response Data: {"certificate":"MIICeDCCAWCgAwIBAgIJANfoTRSlEd4vMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAMGAxCzAJBgNVBAYTAklMMQswCQYDVQQIEwJJTDERMA8GA1UEBxMIU2hlZmF5aW0xDDAKBgNVBAoTA0lCTTESMBAGA1UECxMJV29ya2xpZ2h0MQ8wDQYDVQQDEwZXTCBEZXYwIBcNMTYxMDAxMTAyMDI5WhgPMjA2NjEwMDExMDIwMjlaMF0xITAfBgoJkiaJk\/IsZAEZFhFPZmZsaW5lQXV0aFNhbXBsZTE4MDYGCgmSJomT8ixkAQETKDdmM2U1ZTc3NmY3OTczMDA1YTFiYTU4MWQ5ZTRmYzIwZDZiMjA2N2IwXDANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEFAANLADBIAkEAjspPlIymI497gJwvz8wN5kz5elteLzpNgR\/CMWFIZ3fESDPqa+pyOoUq27MzlhCeF5qCsOQRirOpxCTEiFQwfwIDAQABMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBCwUAA4IBAQCtyM9ayMRlrefJ\/\/9TpGg33Gez\/WiAnOsRLSzCmQGL36Sycny4WrTMKITNSIC9Lgu92PL6lIgqzRUVsepq2\/AXizsZwrjkpFAC4gqzjcgs2C9w+FTRHROayP7xdk532ohL8Q9MyFZjKCkiEJCbLjbWsfywsntmLUHBeg0SehZM\/F5Zv7OD5xTI1mmmjV+\/E12WKwKskXkkJdIAEv+cw1EHYPkr7zzG51jisoK7f+DhMNDAeKJWCxks 2016-10-01 18:20:38.865610 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFinished:] in WLRequest.m:424 :: NSS object is null 2016-10-01 18:20:38.873479 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] BOOL hasCertificateExpired(X509 *) in WLCertManager.m:647 :: Certificate currentDate: 2016-10-01 10:20:38 +0000, expiryDate: 2066-10-01 10:20:29 +0000 2016-10-01 18:20:38.877528 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [WARN] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER]
+[WLCertManager isCertificateVerified:] in WLCertManager.m:572 :: Verification failure: unable to verify the first certificate 2016-10-01 18:20:38.883162 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [CERTIFICATE_MANAGER] +[WLCertManager saveCertificate:withLabel:] in WLCertManager.m:78 :: Certificate saved. 2016-10-01 18:20:38.900978 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252852] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
+[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:52 :: Request url is http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/apps/services/api/OfflineAuthSample/iphone/login 2016-10-01 18:20:38.903341 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252852] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:320 :: Starting the request with URL http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/apps/services/api/OfflineAuthSample/iphone/login 2016-10-01 18:20:39.048286 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:333 :: Request Success 2016-10-01 18:20:39.049534 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:334 :: Response Status Code : 200 2016-10-01 18:20:39.052398 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:335 :: Response Content : /*-secure- {"errorMessage":null,"isSuccessful":true,"authRequired":true}*/ 2016-10-01 18:20:40.510105 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [MC] System group container for systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles path is /private/var/containers/Shared/SystemGroup/systemgroup.com.apple.configurationprofiles 2016-10-01 18:20:40.519465 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [MC] Reading from public effective user settings. 2016-10-01 18:20:47.358122 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252880] [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth 2016-10-01 18:20:47.359112 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [WARN] [USER_CERT_AUTH]
+[WLUserAuthManager getCertificateIdentifier] in WLUserAuthManager.m:68 :: Certificate Identifier Key: com.worklight.userenrollment.certificate:com.OfflineAuthSample 2016-10-01 18:20:47.360715 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252855] 0x17414a3a0 Copy matching assets reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY  <dictionary: 0x17414a3a0> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =  "Result" => <int64: 0x174224a60>: 29 } 2016-10-01 18:20:47.362028 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252855] 0x17414a030 Daemon configuration query reply: XPC_TYPE_DICTIONARY  <dictionary: 0x17414a030> { count = 2, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =   "Dictionary" => <dictionary: 0x17414aa80> { count = 1, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =        "ServerURL" => <dictionary: 0x1741497f0> { count = 3, transaction: 0, voucher = 0x0, contents =             "com.apple.CFURL.magic"
=> <uuid: 0x174243db0> C3853DCC-9776-4114-B6C1-FD9F51944A6D             "com.apple.CFURL.string" => <string: 0x174247080> { length = 30, contents = "https://mesu.apple.com/assets/" }          "com.apple.CFURL.base" => <null: 0x1b0757e80>: null-object      }   }   "Result" => <int64: 0x174229900>: 0 } 2016-10-01 18:20:47.362292 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252855] [MobileAssetError:29] Unable to copy asset information from https://mesu.apple.com/assets/ for asset type com.apple.MobileAsset.TextInput.SpellChecker 2016-10-01 18:20:47.364273 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252855] [DEBUG] [NONE] establishSSLClientAuth isCertificateExists:  false 2016-10-01 18:20:47.365370 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252853] [DEBUG] [NONE] Request [/apps/services/../../invoke] 2016-10-01 18:20:47.373678 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252853] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
+[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:52 :: Request url is http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/invoke 2016-10-01 18:20:47.375603 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252853] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:320 :: Starting the request with URL http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/invoke 2016-10-01 18:20:48.300515 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:333 :: Request Success 2016-10-01 18:20:48.302971 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:334 :: Response Status Code : 200 2016-10-01 18:20:48.306128 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:335 :: Response Content : /*-secure- {"challenges":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"ib694qt4eqq93i5magp7iqf5qh"}}}*/ 2016-10-01 18:20:48.329077 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1253047] [DEBUG] [NONE] response [/apps/services/../../invoke] success: /*-secure- {"challenges":{"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"ib694qt4eqq93i5magp7iqf5qh"}}}*/ 2016-10-01 18:20:48.329486 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] No matching configurations found from the server. Defaulting to local configuration 2016-10-01 18:20:48.341231 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1253047] [TRACE] [WL_AUTH]
-[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:71 :: returning UUID from the keychain 2016-10-01 18:20:48.346860 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1253047] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
+[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:52 :: Request url is http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/apps/services/loguploader 2016-10-01 18:20:48.349978 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1253047] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST]
-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:142 :: Request timeout is 10.000000 2016-10-01 18:20:48.352905 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1253047] [TRACE] [WL_AUTH]
-[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:71 :: returning UUID from the keychain 2016-10-01 18:20:48.356290 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1253047] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:221 :: Sending request (http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/apps/services/loguploader) with headers:  {
    "Accept-Language" = "en-US";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json";
    "User-Agent" = "OfflineAuthSample/1.0 (iPhone; iOS 10.0.1; Scale/3.00)/WLNativeAPI/7.1.0.0";
    "X-Requested-With" = XMLHttpRequest;
    "x-wl-app-version" = "1.0";
    "x-wl-clientlog-appname" = OfflineAuthSample;
    "x-wl-clientlog-appversion" = "1.0";
    "x-wl-clientlog-deviceId" = "A886EC57-DA81-4CF0-8F2D-9A2378124BCB";
    "x-wl-clientlog-env" = iphone;
    "x-wl-clientlog-model" = "iPhone8,2";
    "x-wl-clientlog-osversion" = "10.0.1";
    "x-wl-compressed" = true;
    "x-wl-device-id" = "A886EC57-DA81-4CF0-8F2D-9A2378124BCB";
    "x-wl-platform-version" = "7.1.0.0"; } You can see the request body in the Analytics platform logs. 2016-10-01 18:20:48.375203 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1253047] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:320 :: Starting the request with URL http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/apps/services/loguploader 2016-10-01 18:20:48.377642 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1253047] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] __42-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:]_block_invoke in WLRequest.m:231 :: waiting for response... (Thread=<NSThread: 0x17427f140>{number = 14, name = (null)}) 2016-10-01 18:20:48.382231 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1253047] [TRACE] [WL_AUTH]
-[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:71 ::  returning UUID from the keychain 2016-10-01 18:20:48.384336 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1253047] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
+[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:52 :: Request url is http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/apps/services/loguploader 2016-10-01 18:20:48.388040 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1253047] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST]
-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:142 :: Request timeout is 10.000000 2016-10-01 18:20:48.390529 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1253047] [TRACE] [WL_AUTH]
-[WLDeviceAuthManager getWLUniqueDeviceId] in WLDeviceAuthManager.m:71 :: returning UUID from the keychain 2016-10-01 18:20:48.392962 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1253047] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:221 :: Sending request (http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/apps/services/loguploader) with headers: { "Accept-Language" = "en-US"; "Content-Encoding" = gzip; "Content-Type" = "application/json"; "User-Agent" = "OfflineAuthSample/1.0 (iPhone; iOS 10.0.1; Scale/3.00)/WLNativeAPI/7.1.0.0"; "X-Requested-With" = XMLHttpRequest; "x-wl-app-version" = "1.0"; "x-wl-clientlog-appname" = OfflineAuthSample; "x-wl-clientlog-appversion" = "1.0"; "x-wl-clientlog-deviceId" = "A886EC57-DA81-4CF0-8F2D-9A2378124BCB"; "x-wl-clientlog-env" = iphone; "x-wl-clientlog-model" = "iPhone8,2"; "x-wl-clientlog-osversion" = "10.0.1"; "x-wl-compressed" = true; "x-wl-device-id" = "A886EC57-DA81-4CF0-8F2D-9A2378124BCB"; "x-wl-platform-version" = "7.1.0.0"; } You can see the request body in the Analytics platform logs. 2016-10-01 18:20:48.407261 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1253047] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper start] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:320 :: Starting the request with URL http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/apps/services/loguploader 2016-10-01 18:20:48.409068 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1253047] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] __42-[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:]_block_invoke in WLRequest.m:231 :: waiting for response... (Thread={number = 14, name = (null)}) 2016-10-01 18:20:48.609066 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:333 :: Request Success 2016-10-01 18:20:48.611440 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:334 :: Response Status Code : 201 2016-10-01 18:20:48.614530 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:335 :: Response Content : 2016-10-01 18:20:48.618208 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2015/09/14 00:19:02 2016-10-01 18:20:48.620666 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFinished:] in WLRequest.m:365 :: Response Header: { "Content-Language" = "en-US"; "Content-Length" = 0; Date = "Sat, 01 Oct 2016 10:20:39 GMT"; P3P = "policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE\""; "X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/3.0"; } Response Data: Status code=201 2016-10-01 18:20:48.623068 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFinished:] in WLRequest.m:424 :: NSS object is null 2016-10-01 18:20:48.625059 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [OCLogger] Client Logs successfully sent to server. 2016-10-01 18:20:48.718881 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:333 :: Request Success 2016-10-01 18:20:48.721363 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:334 :: Response Status Code : 201 2016-10-01 18:20:48.724519 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_AFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper_PACKAGE]
-[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestFinished:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:335 :: Response Content : 2016-10-01 18:20:48.728144 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WORKLIGHT] +[WLClient sharedInstance] in WLClient.m:165 :: IBMMobilieFirstFoundation.framework version = 7.1-2015/09/14 00:19:02 2016-10-01 18:20:48.730032 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFinished:] in WLRequest.m:365 :: Response Header: { "Content-Language" = "en-US"; "Content-Length" = 0; Date = "Sat, 01 Oct 2016 10:20:39 GMT"; P3P = "policyref=\"/w3c/p3p.xml\", CP=\"CAO DSP COR CURa ADMa DEVa OUR IND PHY ONL UNI COM NAV INT DEM PRE\""; "X-Powered-By" = "Servlet/3.0"; } Response Data: Status code=201 2016-10-01 18:20:48.732786 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest requestFinished:] in WLRequest.m:424 :: NSS
```

Comment: Using MobileFirst 7.1... iOS 10...IBM MobileFirst Platform Studio 7.1.0.00-20150913-2345... WebSphere Liberty --> WebSphere Application Server V8.5.5.5

Answer (score 0):

From the log, the error is:

> +[WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper requestWithURL:] in WLAFHTTPRequestOperationManagerWrapper.m:52 :: Request url is http://52.77.249.78:9080/testssl/authorization/v1/clients/instance 2016-10-01 18:20:38.665685 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST] -[WLRequest sendRequest:path:withOptions:] in WLRequest.m:142 :: Request timeout is 10.000000 2016-10-01 18:20:38.667459 OfflineAuthSample[3807:1252807] [DEBUG] [WL_REQUEST]

The request seems to have timed out. You should change your network, why would the request time out with the server you're using.

I also see that you're using a device running iOS 10, in which case you should also handle Apple's changed behavior in regards to ATS (Application Transport Security) starting iOS 9.

Read more about ATS in MobileFirst Platform Foundation: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2015/09/09/ats-and-bitcode-in-ios9/